# Why is my sitemap showing a URL that should not be there?

Tags: xmap

I have set up a sitemap for my website using xmap.  In it I've been looking at these two links:

```
www.mydomain.com/
www.mydomain.com/component/content/article/2-english/information/38-welcome
```

The first one is, obviously, the homepage with modules and introduction article.

The second is the introduction article without homepage modules.

I know that the 'welcome' article has id 38, the 'information' category has id 2, and the 'english' category has id 11.
So I'm not sure first of all why "2-english" is being displayed.

I want to remove this URL from my sitemap but I'm not sure where it is being generated from in the first place. In xmap, I have told it to use links from 2 menus on the site and neither of these have a menu item for that url.

Can anyone give me some insight into this please?

Comment: I doubt it's even in your map. I've noticed a pattern with google where it indexes stuff in joomla sites based on some formulas. I'm not even sure how it does it, only that I've found dozens of these kinds of posts listed on google a lot.

Comment: It *is* in the map.  That's what I'm curious about - why did it get there?

Comment: I think it is category "english/information" with category id of 2. Basically, I guess com_content sef ignores anything except the numbers, so there may be slashes inside the category and article names it generates.

Answer (score 2):

If you have got the com_content plugin enabled for Xmap, it will list all items on the menu you have selected - if you are pointing at a category blog or list view on one of your menu items (e.g. English>Information) then each article within English>Information will be featured on the sitemap.

Can you take a look at the front-end view to see the structure?  That might also help figure out why it's outputting in the way you describe.

The URL you're showing looks like it's coming from the category configuration, with the 2- coming from the category ID - are you using any SEF extensions at all, as these will sometimes interfere, and have options whereby you can choose to show the category and article ID within the URL string.